# Bridge/Router with custom logic

Tags: networking, iptables, routing, bridge, nat

I've a Linux box with 3 network adapaters, which I'd like to configure as follow:

1. Adapter A is connected to computer A
2. Adapter B is connected to computer B
3. Adapter C is connected to the Internet. Specifically, to someserver.com

What I want to acheive:

1. All traffic from A will go to the Internet
2. Define a special "secret port" on Adapter B
3. TCP traffic coming from Computer B going to 'someserver.com' on 'secret port' will masquerade its source IP to appear as it is coming from Computer A
4. TCP traffic coming back from 'someserver.com' going to Computer A to the same port used in #3, will redirect to computer B.

Do I need to implement a router or a bridge? Can I do it merely by configuring NetFitler/ip tables or should it implement some code? If code, at which layer to I integrate with the IP stack?

Comment: One thing I do not understand: someserver.com will not see whether the request originated at A or B. (Since all the traffic toward the Internet will have to be masqueraded when leaving C). Am I missing something?

Comment: @Marki, there is no masquerading. A and B have Internet public addresses. The Linux box is either a bridge or a router, but there is no address translation.

Comment: I'd just be too curious about a use case for this.

Comment: @Marki - computers A and B are on the internet. When they go to someserver.com, they always do so from my Linux box (e.g. specific routing). A and B cooperate. On occasion, we want computer B to go to someserver.com without someserver being aware requests are coming from a different machine.

Comment: Ok but that's still not a "use case". Somehow, I don't feel comfortable helping B make it look as though A was the source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For general access, you'll have to use MASQUARADE / SNAT (depending if your IP address on C is dynamic or static).

So let's say current situation is your **computer A** has static IP address `a.a.a.a`, and your **computer B** has static IP address  `b.b.b.b`. Both have default gateway to **computer C**. And **Someserver.com** has static IP address `r.r.r.r` and secret port is `pppp`.

You would configure **computer C** as router, which would have its default route to the Internet **interface C** (it already does that, either via static configuration, or being dynamically setup via PPPoE, etc). That by itself will accomplish `1.`

Now, you have two possibilities:

1. make **computer A** router too.
   Then you change **computer B** config so its default route is via **computer A** (and not **computer C** as before), and  configure **computer A** like this:

   ```
   iptables -t nat -s b.b.b.b -d r.r.r.r -p tcp --dport pppp -j SNAT --to a.a.a.a
   ```

   that would make all TCP packets from source IP `b.b.b.b` going to destination IP `r.r.r.r` and destination port `pppp` pretend like they're coming from `a.a.a.a`, thus accomplishing `3`, and traffic from **someserver.com** will go back to what was source address (`a.a.a.a`), which would be decoded by **computer A** and sent back to **computer B**. (thus accomplishing `4`)

   That is easier, but requires that you computer B is running OS that is capable of such NAT policies.
2. change **computer A** to have private IP like `10.0.1.100/24` and **computer B** to have private IP `10.0.2.100/24`. Then on **computer C** do:

   ```
   ip addr add a.a.a.a/nn dev ifaceC
   ip addr add b.b.b.b/nn dev ifaceC
   iptables -t nat -s 10.0.1.100 -j SNAT --to a.a.a.a
   iptables -t nat -s 10.0.2.100 -d r.r.r.r -p tcp --dport pppp -j SNAT --to a.a.a.a
   iptables -t nat -s 10.0.2.100 -j SNAT --to b.b.b.b
   ```

   where `nn` is your netmask and `ifaceC` is name of your **interface C**. That would put **computer A** and **computer B** in private ranges, thus allowing **computer C** to NAT **computer A** to `a.a.a.a` (so it behaves like before), and NAT **computer B** either to `a.a.a.a` (if dst=`r.r.r.r`, dport=`pppp` condition is met) or to `b.b.b.b` (otherwise).

This does not require any special support on **computer A** nor **computer B**, but puts them behind [NAT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation) which might affect some other things.

And of course, it this age it should be mentioned that above will only work for good ol' [IPv4](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv4) addresses (the last of which are [rapidly being used up](http://www.potaroo.net/tools/ipv4/index.html)) and not on [IPv6](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6)

Comment: Thank you. #1 will not work for my configuration. For option 2: If computers A and B both have public address. Can I have a.a.a.a and b.b.b.b be 10.0.1.100 and 10.0.1.101 (their own IP) respectively?
Also, can you recommend a good resource for setting up a router?

Comment: No, you must remove public addresses from them, and setup private addresses instead (like recommended 10.0.1.*). That is because with `ip addr add` you will move public addresses from A and B to C, so it can do NAT for them, and they must not be present elsewhere! For setting up a router, you should first have excellent knowledge of how TCP/IP works in general, and then apply it to specific router. For later step for generic GNU/Linux machines, [LARTC](http://lartc.org/howto/) is good intro.

Answer (score 1):

Per your comment:

> @Marki - computers A and B are on the internet. When they go to
>   someserver.com, they always do so from my Linux box (e.g. specific
>   routing). A and B cooperate. On occasion, we want computer B to go to
>   someserver.com without someserver being aware requests are coming from
>   a different machine.

Am I missing something here?  If you set Computer C up as a Router, the requests from A and B won't matter.  The Private/Public IP Addresses from both A and B will both be exchanged with the Public IP Address from Computer C, according to the rules of NAT.  Therefore if C is the last Gateway in the chain for your network, *someserver* will see all requests coming from C, and C will route them back to A and B.

In order for this to work, Computer C, needs two network cards, one connected to the private LAN, and the other connected to the Public WAN.

Below is Matija's Number 2
If you want Computer B to mimic Computer A, B must filter it's traffic through A before reaching C.  I don't see how this help's your "use case" as computer C only sees traffic from computer A, **but regardless**:

*Someserver* will never see a private address from A or B.  You're overkilling the situation here, as all you need to do is enable port forwarding on computer C so that all ports get forward to the private IP address for Computer B.

Comment: I apologize I wasn't clear about it. There are no private addresses. A and B have *public* Internet addresses. They route through C, but there is no NAT involved. I do want to change the source address when B is going to the Interneton specific scenarios (e.g. specific port on someserver) to A. In normal scenarios, someserver gets the public source address of A.

Comment: Whether A and B Are public or not, setup a DHCP Server on C that gives A and B public Addresses, then setup port Forwarding to the Public IP Address on B for the specific ports you want to watch.  When Routing to the Internet someserver will only see the requests coming from C, but B will be reachable because it's Public.

Answer (score 0):

You solve this problem by installing a proxy on A which will listen for B/SecretPort and forward it to SomeServer. Answers picked on A with SecretPort are forwarded to B.